# Setting id of View using String Android SDK

Tags: android, view, identifier

I know you can set the int id of a View using the following:

```
 View.setId(int id);
```

But is there a way to use a string instead? I know what I could do is declare an array of arrays and each array contains a string and an int associated with that string and if the string is called then it gets the int associated with that string, but is there a simpler way to do it to set the id a as a string?

Also, when a View is created during runtime on the app, does it automatically generate a unique int id for it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: why would you use a String id?

Comment: Because I am making an app that requires the use of a string id for users so they don't have to deal with integers that might get confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 but is there a simpler way to do it to set the id a as a string?
```

No, there is no. View has just the setId(int) method. If your string is a number, you can convert this to int and use as id for your view.

> Also, when a View is created during runtime on the app, does it
>   automatically generate a unique int id for it?

no you have to take care of it.

Comment: So, if that's the case, could I implement it in such a way where in a loop it detects if an int id exists already? Using the getId method?

Comment: @user3864563 that's what will be returned if there's no ID associated with this `View` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#NO_ID

Comment: since api level 17 android introduced the method generateViewId. You can take a look to ist implmentation here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/view/View.java#View.generateViewId%28%29